# How to copy a file in Java

Tags: java, android, compilation

I'm using Android Studio. Is there a possible command that will copy say, a picture in your DCIM folder and moves it to the root directory of the SD card? I have researched around and I have found nothing. I have decompiled other apps and found nothing. As you can probably tell I am a beginner to average programer. I just began Java for this project.

Even if there is not I would like to know so I can stop racking the web for answers :P

Thanks, All comments welcome, Will post more info If needed! :)

Comment: Java Tutorial to copy files: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) + Example of copy Files in Java: [Link](http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java)

Comment: Post that as a awnser and Ill select it

Comment: Search for file handling operations in java.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function

```
public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile)
            throws IOException {

        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        FileInputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            source = is.getChannel();
            destination = os.getChannel();

            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while ((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size
                    - count)) < size)
                ;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do i input my file directory at in this? I believe this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

To copy file you can use following:

```
File fileToCopy = new File("path to file you want to copy");
File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"filename");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToCopy);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int noOfBytesRead;

while((noOfBytesRead = fis.read(b)) != -1)
     fos.write(b,0,noOfBytesRead);
fis.close();
fos.close();
```